# shell: any way to use `uniq -c` taking into account a prior `uniq -c`?

Tags: shell, uniq

I'm doing some data processing in a UNIX shell (OS X).

After using `uniq -c` and doing some further look-up based processing, I sort the data all over again, and need to use `uniq -c` one more time, but keep in mind the results of the prior counts (e.g. count the counts).

E.g. if the input data is something like this:

```
36351 | 3
36351 | 2
36351 | 13
2914 | 1
2914 | 2
```

Then the output should be something like this:

```
36351 | 18
2914 | 3
```

(The order of the fields is not substantial.)

How do I do this in shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to get `uniq` to do the job, but it's pretty trivial with awk:

```
    { c[$1] += $3; } 

END { for (s in c) printf("%s | %s\n", s, c[s]); }
```

Comment: If the values for a key are always guaranteed to be adjacent, you could get away with very little memory, too; but unless you have absolutely huge input, this hardly matters.